# String splitting into textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I am using the following technique to dynamically update a textbox -

**Code behind**

```
Lat.DataSource = ws.returnLAT(place);
Lat.DataBind();
```

**aspx code**

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="Lat">
<ItemTemplate>

<td>
<asp:Label for="latBox" ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Latitude"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="latBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>'></asp:TextBox>
</td>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

One debugging, `DataSource` is equal to `99`, however when presented in the web page, that value is split into two separate text boxes each with a single `9` in them instead of the desired single textbox with `99` in it.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What does `ws.returnLAT(place)` actually return? So there's really a second `TextBox` visible after the first `latBox`? Can you show/link a screenshot?

Comment: It returns the 99 value.

Comment: So it does return a single `int` with value 99? You couldn't use that as datasource, so what's the signature of `returnLAT`, what type does it return?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what it does but for some reason that int is getting split into two values. returnLAT returns the int as a string using a webserivce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening here is it's (for whatever reason) treating `99` as 2 separate records. You shouldn't really be passing a single value as a `DataSource` it should be some form of *collection*.

For example, if you changed your binding code to:

```
Lat.DataSource = new List<int>(1) { ws.returnLat(place) };
```

Does the problem go away?

Comment: Your solution has worked a treat, however the reason it is a single value at present is for proof of concept, however it is likely that it will change to multiple values at a later date, will this have to be modified when that occurs?

Comment: If `ws.returnLat(...)` returns some form of collection i.e. `IEnumerable<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, `IList<T>`, `List<T>` etc. then you can safely assign it straight to the `DataSource`.